# Cannot figure out Seg Fault, lots of detail provided

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, state-machine

I asked this question about a half hour ago, but the code had typos and I wasn't being very clear, so I've deleted and I'm trying again with a better format.

I'm getting a Segmentation Fault in my code, the problem seems to be at the function call `if( (*trans).test((*this), *(*itr)) )` inside `World::update()`:

```
void World::update(sf::Time dt)
{
    mPlayer->setVelocity(0.f, 0.f);

    while (!mCommandQueue.isEmpty()){
                Command cmd = mCommandQueue.pop();
                cmd.action(cmd.node, dt);
    }
    mSceneGraph.update(dt);
    adaptPlayerPosition();

    //Enemy Spawn engine
    if (mSpawnTimer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() >= SPAWN_INTERVAL && mEnemies.size() < MAX_NUM_ENEMIES){
        float winX = mWindow.getDefaultView().getSize().x;
        float winY = mWindow.getDefaultView().getSize().y;
        float x = rand() % (int)winX;
        float y = rand() % (int)winY;
        spawnEnemy(x, y, EnemyType::Loner, IState::ILWander);
        mSpawnTimer.restart();
    }

    // FSM update
    IState::ID curEnemyStateID;
    FState curEnemyState;
    bool trigger = false;
    ICondition triggeredtrans;
    FState triggeredState;
    for(auto itr = mEnemies.begin(); itr != mEnemies.end(); ++itr){
        curEnemyStateID = (*itr)->getState();

        // set curState to whatever the enemy's curState is
        switch(curEnemyStateID){
        case 0:
            curEnemyState = LWander;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        auto tState = curEnemyState.getTransitionStates().begin();
        for(auto trans = curEnemyState.getConditions().begin(); trans != curEnemyState.getConditions().end(); ++trans){
            if( (*trans).test((*this), *(*itr)) ){
                trigger = true;
                triggeredState = (*tState);
                break;
            }
            ++tState;
        }
        if(trigger){
            (*itr)->setState(IState::ILRushPlayer);
            curEnemyState = LRushPlayer;
        }
        curEnemyState.getAction()->doAction((*this), *(*itr));
    }
}
```

---

Context:

`trans` is an iterator for a `std::vector<ICondition> conditions` where each `ICondition` has a `test(World& world, Enemy& enemy)`. `itr` is an iterator through a `std::vector<Enemy*>` that is held by `World`.

The `conditions` vector is filled in this function:

```
void World::initializeStates()
{
    Wander LWanderAction;
    LWander.setAction(LWanderAction);

    DistFromPlayer LWanderCond1(30);

    LWander.pushCondition(LWanderCond1);
    LWander.pushTransitionState(LRushPlayer);
}
```

LWander is a state (`FState`) in my Finite State Machine. `Wander` is a class that inherits `IAction`, and `setAction` accepts an `IAction` parameter: `FState::setAction(IAction iact)`

`DistFromPlayer` is a class that inherits `ICondition`.

`FState::pushCondition(ICondition icond)` and `FState::pushTransitionState(Fstate state)` should take their arguments and push them to `Fstate`'s `conditions` and `states` vectors. (A transition's condition and matching target state should be at the same indices in both)

`LWander` and `LRushPlayer` are both members of `World`.

---

And that should cover everything. I don't know why I'm getting a SegFault, but I'm assuming that the problem is with how things are pushed into `LWander` in `World::initializeStates()`. I should also note that the SegFault occurs right after the first enemy is spawned in my game, which is also the same update frame that runs `(*trans).test(*this, **itr)` for the first time. All `Enemy`s start in the `LWander` state.

---

ICondition's `virtual bool test(World& world, Enemy& enemy);` is defined as:

```
bool ICondition::test(World& world, Enemy& enemy){
    return false;
    //returns false by default, overwritten later
}
```

and DistFromPlayer's `bool test(World& world, Enemy& enemy);` is defined as:

```
bool DistFromPlayer::test(World& world, Enemy& enemy)
{
    std::cout << "DistFromPlayer (LWander's Transition) was reached\n";
    return false;
}
```

and only contains a print statement for debugging purposes.

---

GDB's backtrace

```
#0  World::update (this=0x6464408, dt=...) at C:\...\World.cpp:97
#1  0x0040416b in GameState::update (this=0x64643f0, dt=...) at C:\...\GameState.cpp:22
#2  0x00402435 in StateStack::update (this=0x28fde0, dt=...) at C:\...\StateStack.cpp:19
#3  0x00403782 in Game::update (this=0x28fbc0, elapsedTime=...) at C:\...\Game.cpp:58
#4  0x004036a2 in Game::run (this=0x28fbc0) at C:\...\Game.cpp:48
#5  0x0040888b in main () at C:\...\main.cpp:7
```

Comment: How do you know that "the problem *seems* to be at this function call"? Have you run your program in a debugger to find out? If so, what's the function call stack? What is the values of involved variables?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I ran it through Code::Block's Debugger, and the function stack is main()->Game::run()->Game::update()->StateStack::update()->GameState::update()->World::update()-> ??() Which is exactly what I expect it to be. `(*trans)` should be set to the first element in `LWander.conditions`, which should be of type `public DistFromPlayer : public ICondition` and `**itr` should be of type `public Enemy`

Comment: This screams 'dereferencing an invalid iterator' to me... are you modifying the vectors for which trans and itr are iterators at any point in the loop? It might even be helpful to see all of the World::update() function while you're at it, if it's not absurdly large

Comment: @Commander I haven't changed the trans or itr iterators' vectors, at any point during the loops. I edited the post to show the whole `World::update()`

Comment: I also added a `if (trans != curEnemyState.getConditions().end() && itr != mEnemies.end())` and it passed, so it looks like they are both valid iterators.

Comment: Hmm. What about that `auto tState = curEnemyState.getTransitionStates().begin();` immediately before your loop? There's a `++tState;` within that loop, and you never check whether your `tState == curEnemyState.getTransitionStates().end()` at any point - do you possibly advance that iterator past the end of its vector without realizing?

Comment: Also, you're storing a bunch of objects that inherit from ICondition by value in a vector of IConditions - sounds like you might be a victim of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Comment: @Commander The purpose to that line is having an iterator running through `states` parallel to the iterator going through `conditions`. Both vectors should have the same number of elements, and shouldn't it not even matter if the segfault happens before any call to tState?

Comment: You may be right on that - as long as you're not touching those vectors anywhere that you don't show here, they should be in sync enough for you to do that, though it's riskyyyy. Anyways, second problem - you push back `LWanderCond1` onto LWander's `conditions()` vector, which is pushing back a derived object into a container of its parents - meaning you could be deleting all of the member variables and functionality of the derived class without knowing (as you stuff the object into a too-small container) then trying to access those members. You might need vectors of pointers instead.

Comment: @Commander I've made the change: `std::vector<ICondition*> conditions` and `(*trans)->test((*this), *(*itr))` But I seem to still be getting the SegFault, so I guess those problems weren't related.

Comment: Could you run your program with gdb (or other debugger) and -O0 (no optimization) and give us backtrace?

Comment: @klm123 I added the function stack in the second comment, but Ill put the full GDB >bt output to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting tState iterator. You only initialize it with begin() and increment it. I can't find any test against end() of the appropriate container. Or is it safe because of some relation between curEnemyState.getTransitionStates() and curEnemyState.getConditions() which I don't realize?

Comment: the `conditions` and the `states` vectors should have the same length, where one condition's target state is kept in the same index in `states` as the condition is in `conditions`. Therefore if I increment them together, then I have access to a condition and it's target state. However, this code is not related to the segfault, as the program crashes before the first call to `tState`.

Comment: Ok, get it. It might be useful to know exact source of segfault. I am not sure about your platform - could you use valgrind (if on linux) or some alternative (if on windows)?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm kind of new to programming, let alone using a debugger. What do you mean by source of segfault? According to Code::Blocks, which uses GDB I think, the program crashes on `(*trans).test((*this), *(*itr)) )` as I stated. if you mean which of those pointers is causing it, then I'm pretty sure `(*this)` isn't the problem, and I'm trying to find out if perhaps when I fill `conditions` with `IConditions` or `mEnemies` with `Enemies`, maybe I'm doing it incorrectly, so the iterators wont be working properly. I created a new question asking if I'm filling `mEnemies` correctly.

Comment: I see. Could you then provide definition of that ICondition::test() method?

Comment: I added it to the bottom of the original post. If you had time and so desired, we could commune over a VoIP also.