# passing a pointer to two different places, different results?

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

In this code, I want to create an `Enemy` object, and push a pointer of it to two different places: as a child in the tree of all my drawable objects (`Enemy` is drawable), and to a list of `Enemy*`'s called `mEnemies` that keeps track of all active `Enemy` objects, without having to iterate through my graph.

```
void World::spawnEnemy(float x, float y, EnemyType::ID type, IState::ID state)
{
        Enemy* enemy(new Enemy(mTextures, type, state));
        enemy->setPosition(x, y);
        mEnemies.push_back( enemy );
        mSceneLayers[Air]->attachChild( enemy );
}
```

When my code tries to draw the graph of drawable nodes, it succeeds with the correct position as specified in the above function. However, when I create an iterator `auto itr` for `mEnemies` and try to access `(**itr)`, then the debugger says that it is an `Enemy` with completely nonsensical values, and I get a seg fault when I try to access.

For referance, the `attachChild` code looks like this:

```
void SceneNode::attachChild(SceneNode* child)
{
        child->mParent = this;
        mChildren.push_back(child);
}
```

Other related code is in my other question: [Cannot figure out Seg Fault, lots of detail provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394749/cannot-figure-out-seg-fault-lots-of-detail-provided)

Comment: When is this iterator created? Are you inserting into the vector *after* creating the iterator? If this is the case, the iterator is not guaranteed to be valid.

Comment: Be careful not to delete your objects (and still have reference/pointers to them), you might want to take a look at reference counting

Comment: @AndyG Nothing is added to the vectors after the iterator is created. @Paranaix Do the `Enemy` objects that I make in `spawnEnemy` get destroyed at the end of the function? If this happens, why does the `Enemy` still get drawn by the `SceneNode` graph?

Comment: Why do you dereference like this **iter...shouldnt it just be *iter

Comment: @JoshEngelsma: *iter will return a pointer to an enemy, **iter will return the actual object.

Comment: yes, but do you have to dereference the pointer to enemy?

Comment: @JoshEngelsma: Have to? No, well maybe. If you want. Point is, if the OP wants to mess with the enemy object by dereferencing the pointer returned from a dereferenced iterator, s/he can. It's not illegal or (inherently) dangerous.

Comment: @AndyG you're right, I was just wondering why you would want too...agreed, not illegal

Comment: @user3051585: We are going to need more code. At least show us how you are iterating through, and maybe some more logic. Ideally, a small compileable example that fully recreates your bug would be nice, but I understand that may be a big undertaking in this case.

Comment: @AndyG I've posted my other question which has more code relating to where `itr` gets called, but I believe you already found it earlier. I don't think I can recreate this problem in a small program, but I will try.

Comment: @user3051585: Can enemies die? What happens in code when they do? Do you simply call `delete` on the pointer? Do you make sure you unattach the child from its parent by calling `erase` on the parent's child vector? Do you make sure you call `erase` on mEnemies after calling `delete`? If you don't delete the memory, what do you do with the pointers? Change a state variable to read DEAD or something? I think this information would be very useful.

Comment: @AndyG In this build, enemies cannot die, and for debugging purposes I set the game to only spawn one. The seg fault happens the frame that the first enemy is spawned (which, strangely enough is NOT the first time **itr gets called, so perhaps these enemies are working, in which case I guess this code would be working properly. My main question was making sure that `world.mEnemies` and the node graph are both enemy pointers that point to the same data, and to make sure I don't accidentally destroy that Enemy data somewhere in my code.)